# How to add new property to an object after select from mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql

iam reading some data out of a mysql database with prepared statement in plain php. 
After that i want to add one new property and a value to this property for every data set.

So as an example, when i have this kind of data, after reading out the mysql:

```
[{                                                                   
  firstname: "John",lastname:"Peter",department:"wsed4"                      
},{                                                                  
   firstname: "Daniel",lastname:"McGregor",department:"asdf2"           
}]
```

I want to add the property **branch**  with the value  **2** to the data. so it may look like this.

```
[{ 
    firstname: "John",lastname:"Peter",department:"wsed4", branch:"2" 
},
{
    firstname: "Daniel",lastname:"McGregor",department:"asdf2",branch:"2" 
}]
```

Here is the php code for reading out the data from a mysql db.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT firstname,lastname, department from person WHERE companyid = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$companyid);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Now i want to walk through the result and add to every data set the new property **branch** to it with the value 2.

I have tried it on different ways but it did not work.
Here is an example of one try of millions :))

```
  $persons = $result->fetch_assoc();

  foreach($persons as $person){    
      $persObj = $person->fetch_object(); 
      $persObj->branch = "2";
  }
```

There is allways an error.
I need the data in json in the frontend.
Please help how to add new property to result of mysql select.

Comment: Could you provide us the Error Message? It might makes it easier for us to help.

Comment: [`mysqli_fetch_result`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) returns a single result, so your foreach is iterating through the columns of the first result. You'll want [`fetch_all`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), and skip the `fetch_object`. Or iterate through `$persons->fetchObject()`, add the branch, then assign the object to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want **always** 2 as branch, you can build your query such as

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, department, 2 AS branch from person WHERE companyid = ?");
//                                                            ^---------^---- Check this
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching an associative array

```
while($persons = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $persons['branch'] = 2;
}
```